# Null when splitting a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, split

I need to create my own sort method for an array, and I begin my splitting the text file into an array filled with the words. The file format is: an integer n, followed by n words.

Here's an example: 4 hello hello world hello

However, my array prints: [null4, hello, hello, world, hello]

WHY! I don't understand why there is a null before. And, if I remove the number 4 (which plays no role in my program at the moment) I get: [nullhello, hello, world, hello]

Can you please help me remove this null? Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    filePath = "***TEXT FILE HERE***";

    fileInput = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
    convertFile(fileInput);
}

public static void convertFile(Scanner file) {

    String line;

    while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
        line = fileInput.nextLine();
        fileData = fileData + line;
    }

    String[] array = createArray(fileData);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static String[] createArray(String data) {
    String[] dataArray = data.split("\\s+");

    return dataArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialise the `fileData` variable before using it.

try

```
fileData = "";
```

Comment: If it worked for you, do accept the answer by pressing the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileData = fileData + line;
```

this is not the best choise for building a string... try to replace it with a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder(); // to instantiate
fileData.append(line + "\n"); // to add lines
String finalString = fileData.toString(); // to build the string
```

for larger strings your method of concatenation will become very slow